# Get total number of elements in jagged array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, multidimensional-array, count, jagged-arrays

I have an array of bytes that is declared:

```
Dim commands As Byte()()
```

The array is later filled with a bunch of byte values, in my current test it results in a rectangular 3x3 array (the rectilinearity is coincidental, the array may hold byte arrays of any length).

```
commands = New Byte(3)(){}
'...
commands(i) = GetBytes(x)
```

Later still I would like to obtain a count of the total number of bytes within the jagged array. I assumed `Array.Length` would do this as it's description says

> The total number of elements in all the dimensions of the Array

However, it seems to *actually* only be returning 4; the count of the first dimension of the array, that is the `GetLength(0)` or number of rows. `Array.Count` also returns the same (i.e. 3).

Have I correctly understood what `Array.Length` should return? If I have, then why is it not returning 9?

**P.S:** I did try with other size arrays and `Length` is definitely returning `GetLength(0)`
[image: screenshot showing offending values]

Comment: The samples on the MSDN page you reference are using 1-2-3d arrays, not jagged arrays.  It sounds like you expect it to scan the *contents* to count those elements?

Comment: @Plutonix Hmph, yeah kinda! XD So basically the array type in VB is really as dumb as an intrinsic type?

Comment: In a 3D array those other dimensions are actually part of the array object (ie commands), not so in a jagged array.  in that case, they are just the contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Have I correctly understood what Array.Length should return? If I have, then why is it not returning 9?

Not entirely.  The top level array *does* only have 3 elements, which is what its `Length` property is reporting.  It's just that those elements happen to *also* be arrays.

You'll need to loop over (or write a linq query etc) to get the total count across all arrays, for example:

```
Dim total as Integer = 0
For Each subarray as Byte() In commands
    total += subarray.Length
Next
```

---

The other issue you have here is that you have an array of arrays, rather than a multidimensional array, which would be declared as:

```
Dim commands as Byte(,)
```

This is now a *single* array, where the `Length` property would return you a count of *all* the elements.

Comment: I get what you mean, but the fact that the MSDN description specifically says "all dimensions" kinda implies the exact opposite, wouldn't you say?

Comment: Just saw @Plutonix's second comment - explains it a bit more...-ish. Still seems like the description is *very* misleading :\

Comment: Are VB jagged array elements not stored sequentially, as multi-dimensional arrays are, then?

Comment: You mean in actual memory?  That's an implementation detail that different .NET runtimes might do differently.

Comment: Anyway, I went with `commands.Sum(Function(c) c.Length))`, Ta